# Getting a 500 internal server error when setting JwtBearerOptions Authority

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Can someone explain what's going on wrong here.

I am getting an error if I set the `Authority` of `JwtBearerOption`s to "`https://localhost:7089/`"

When I comment it out it seems to work fine.  Do I not need to set the `Authority` here?

If I set the Authority, I get a

> 500 Internal Server Error

This is my code in Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, c =>
    {
        c.Authority = @$"https://localhost:7089/"; // causing error!!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        c.Audience = @$"https://localhost:7089/";
        c.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "https://localhost:7089/",
            ValidIssuer = $"https://localhost:7089/",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ZCI6Imp1c3RteWlkIiwibmJmIjoxNjU0NzQxNDE1LCJleHAiOjE2NTQ")),
            ValidateLifetime = false,
        };

    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", [AllowAnonymous] () =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
});

app.MapPost("/security/getToken", [AllowAnonymous] (string username, string password) =>
{

    if (username == "username" && password == "password")
    {
        var issuer = @$"https://localhost:7089/";
        var audience = @$"https://localhost:7089/";
        var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ZCI6Imp1c3RteWlkIiwibmJmIjoxNjU0NzQxNDE1LCJleHAiOjE2NTQ"));

        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);
        var claims = new[]
        {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email , "test@test.com")
    };

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {

            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim("Id", "testID")
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
            NotBefore = DateTime.Now,
            Audience = audience,
            Issuer = issuer,
            SigningCredentials = credentials

        };
        var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        var jwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return Results.Ok(jwtToken);
    }
    else
    {
        return Results.Unauthorized();
    }

});

app.MapGet("/securepage", [Authorize] () =>
{


    List<string> vals = new List<string>() { "test", "test", "test", "test" };
    return vals;
});

app.Run();

internal record WeatherForecast(DateTime Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

Error detail:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: The 'localhost' scheme is not supported.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Do you have a valid certificate?

Comment: Is there a real token service listening at `https://localhost:7089/`?

Comment: @DavidOsborne no.. i don't have one set up.. if i don't set it that means the Authority is null right?  how does that work then?

Comment: It depends on whether the authority needs to be contacted in any way. To get metadata or verify tokens. What's issuing your tokens?